# Setting max-height AND min-height property in CSS (or via jQuery)

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a simple but annoying problem. I need to set `min-height` AND `max-height` of a div element.

For example: `min-height: 100px` and `max-height: 200px`. I load my page with div height 200px. If i squeeze my browser window, this div resizes and when it hits `height=100px` it stops resizing.

Of course `min-height` and `max-height` in CSS is not working. :/

Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is not working? This can't work if you set `height` to 200px. What happens if you use a relative value for `height`?

Comment: I doesn't shrink to 100px height when I squeeze my browser window. It just stays at 200px.

Answer (score 6):

Also set *height*.

```
min-height: 100px;
max-height: 200px;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Not working either :[ It just sets height to 200px and when i squeeze my broser window it doesn't shrink to 100px. It just stays with 200px height.

#wrap {
 background: #ff0000;
 min-height: 100px;
 max-height: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: @Pon: That does work. You must have something else on your page that is interfering. Can you produce a minimal example with that style that doesn't work for you? Also, what browser are you testing in?

Comment: I have the same issue. When shrinking the page, it keeps the max-height if I add the height 100%, if not, then it keeps the min-height. my div is positioned fixed.

Comment: You could try `height: 100vh;` instead of `height: 100%;`. Using a % height is finicky since it requires a defined height for its container, while vh does not

Answer (score 3):

Min height always overwrites height and max-height, so you can't just use both.

This is kind of a hack, but you could do it with media queries. If this is your HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Then add this to your css:

```
#myDiv{
    height:200px;    
}
@media screen and (max-height: 200px) {
    #myDiv {
        height:99vh; /*Set this with trial and error because it depends on your margins*/
    }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 100px) {
    #myDiv {
        height:100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use both, but the min-height will take precedence if it ever conflicts with max-height or height.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
min-height: 100px;
max-height: 200px;
height: 100vh;
```